# what is the alternative for not to hard-code licence key of jwplayer in metadata of android manifest

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, xamarin, jwplayer

I'm working on JwPlayer and found that the License key should be given in metadata

```
<meta-data
            android:name="JW_LICENSE_KEY"
            android:value="seFyAWPdupaTE/IHIzRQLiJZmw8w0hyN9IZo23oerxapzQQZ3kVuoRgaqqcvwWBG" />
```

But I want to send it from server for my multi behavior app. Which will look for videos in different account, based on users.

So i tried to write meta data dynamically like below but it wasn't working.

```
try {
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            applicationInfo.metaData.putString("JW_LICENSE_KEY",
                    "seFyAWPdupaTE/IHIzRQLiJZmw8w0hyN9IZo23oerxapzQQZ3kVuoRgaqqcvwWBG");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Is there any way to not hard-code `license key` in android manifest for `JwPlayer` ?**

Comment: It's a requirement from JwPlayer, you should probably check with their support team see if they actually support dynamic keys.

Comment: @Manoj they are not answering so i asked here

Comment: Hope someone with JWPlayer background could answer that. But just so you know simply tagging all the platforms not going help.

Comment: @Manoj I thought it's a universal issue. thank you